# mu-plugins body_class filter not working

Tags: filters, cookies, body-class, mu-plugins

So this code was working fine in mu-plugins until an update back in september or so...

```
function save_cookie_class( $classes ) {
    array_push( $classes, isset($_COOKIE['some_cookie']) );
    array_push( $classes, isset($_COOKIE['other_cookie']) );
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'save_cookie_class' );
```

Any ideas why it mightn't be working?

Comment: What's not working in the code?

Comment: Your function will add either `TRUE` and `FALSE`, `TRUE` and `TRUE`, `FALSE` and `TRUE` or `FALSE` and `FALSE` to the body class - are you sure this is what you want?